# After deploying the project to digital ocean it throws this error when click sign in or sign up buttons

Tags: node.js, angular, express, deployment, digital-ocean

[image]

What can cause such an issue? After the first deployment, it worked fine second time it cause such an issue. Project is built with Node.js and Angular6

Comment: Aparently, your code tries to make an AJAX request to `http://localhost:3000` instead of making AJAX requests to the actual host where your API is deployed. You need to fix your code and use the correct URL.

Comment: I assume inside server.js I should change this part?
server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Listening on port 3000');
});

Comment: How should it look like?

Comment: No. The problem is that the **client** code is sending an **AJAX request** to localhost. You need to change the client code to send a request to the correct URL. If you go to google.com, you type google.com in your browser address bar, not localhost, right? Same here.